# Sort posts by highest vote count?

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT 
links.id, 
links.url, 
links.user_id, 
links.title, 
links.description, 
links.nsfw, 
links.posted, 
links.category_id,

votes.vote
votes.vote_date

FROM links 

INNER JOIN votes
ON votes.link_id = links.id

ORDER BY (I want to sort by the count of votes on the links) DESC
```

If I want to sort my links/posts by votes, how can I then do it with this SQL?
The link with the highest vote count shows first.

Comment: The thing is unclear. You want a list of links sorted by *average* vote? By most voted? By highest-given-vote? ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want grouping. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  links.id, 
  links.url, 
  links.user_id, 
  links.title, 
  links.description, 
  links.nsfw, 
  links.posted, 
  links.category_id
FROM 
  links 
  INNER JOIN votes ON votes.link_id = links.id
GROUP BY links.id
ORDER BY COUNT(votes.id) DESC
```

I didn't test it (because I don't have your dataset), but it should be more or less correct.

Comment: I believe he does *not* want to group.

Comment: I believe he _does_ want highest voted posts. How to provide that without grouping on links?

Comment: Yeah, I admit it's pretty difficult. I suppose that's why we had to ask ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Group by link id and select thee vot count

   ```
   SELECT
       count(*) as votecount,
       links.id, 
       links.url, 
       links.user_id, 
       links.title, 
       links.description, 
       links.nsfw, 
       links.posted, 
       links.category_id,
       votes.vote
       votes.vote_date
   FROM links 
   INNER JOIN votes
       ON votes.link_id = links.id
   GROUP BY links.id
   ```

2.) Wrap this in a superquery for sorting

```
SELECT * FROM (
    <as above>
) AS baseview
ORDER BY votecount DESC
```

Comment: The difference between this solution and the one by @SergeiTulentsev is, that the inner query will go to the query cache. Assuming you might need it for display later on, this is a good thing.

Comment: query cache gets invalidated on every table mutation. So I never rely on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT links.id, links.url, votes.vote, votes.vote_date
FROM links
INNER JOIN votes ON votes.link_id = links.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT links.id AS link_id, COUNT(votes.id) AS num_votes
    FROM links
    INNER JOIN votes ON votes.link_id = links.id
    GROUP BY links.id
) AS votes_per_link ON links.id=votes_per_link.link_id
ORDER BY votes_per_link.num_votes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't understand which of these behaviors you are asking for, I post solutions to different cases here:

Get links, order by highest vote:

```
SELECT votes.link_id, links.url, MAX(votes.vote) AS maxvote
FROM votes INNER JOIN links ON links.id = votes.link_id
GROUP BY votes.link_id ORDER BY `maxvote` DESC;
```

Get links, order by average vote:

```
SELECT votes.link_id, links.url, AVG(votes.vote) AS avgvote
FROM votes INNER JOIN links ON links.id = votes.link_id
GROUP BY votes.link_id ORDER BY `avgvote` DESC;
```

Get links, order by votes count:

```
SELECT votes.link_id, links.url, COUNT(votes.vote) AS cntvotes
FROM votes INNER JOIN links ON links.id = votes.link_id
GROUP BY votes.link_id ORDER BY `cntvotes` DESC;
```

Get votes, by highest vote:

```
SELECT links.id, links.url, votes.vote
FROM links INNER JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.link_id
ORDER BY votes.vote DESC;
```

(I omitted some fields to shorten queries, of course feel free to add them back again).